# Multithreading code on button click event leaves the application in a hung state

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, datagridview

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MteWindowsForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            AddCols();
            AddRows();

        }

        void AddRows()
        {
            dgv.Rows.Add(10000);
            bool istrue = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
                {
                    if (istrue)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = "SomeText";
                        istrue = !istrue;
                    }
                    else istrue = !istrue;
                }
            }
        }
        void AddCols()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn dgvCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                string strText = "Column_" + i;
                dgvCol.Name = strText;
                dgvCol.HeaderText = strText;
                dgvCol.FillWeight = 1;
                dgv.Columns.Add(dgvCol);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //lock empty cells
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my form looks like:

[image]

However on clicking `Button1` the application stays like that and does nothing. My algorithm is simple - i am dividing the datagridview columns count from `0->n/2` and `n/2+1->n` and locking a bunch of columns and unlocking the rest.

Please help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - How and where?

Comment: He means that if your main thread calls Thread.Join to wait for a background thread, it isn't pumping messages and thus responding to Invoke

Comment: How can i resolve this?

Comment: The best way to resolve it is to get rid of the multithreaded code; it's providing no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

There's the potential deadlock mentioned in the comments, and while I'm not sure if that is the case, the hanging of the application is caused by the lines

```
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

`Join` is telling the UI thread that it should block until these threads are finished. You either need a separate callback/event to fire when the threads complete, or, if you're using .NET 4.5, you can use the Task Async capabilities and use `await` on your background thread calls.

Check out this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async) on how to use the new async/await keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your application has got a [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). Your worker thread waits in `dgv.Invoke` for main thread to complete, at the same time your main thread waits in `Join` for workers to complete indefinitely hence results in deadlock.

You're using `Thread` where it is unnecessary. I mean your `LockCols` method is completely dealing with `UI` so you must run it in UI. by running the loop in other thread you're not going to get any benefit. Following code is better version of yours.

```
void LockCols(int istart, int iend, bool isReadOnly)
{
    for (int idx = istart; idx < iend; idx++)
    {
        if (isReadOnly)
        {
             dgv.Columns[idx].ReadOnly = isReadOnly;
             dgv.Columns[idx].HeaderText = dgv.Columns[idx].Name + "_" + "ReadOnly";

        }
        else
        {
             dgv.Columns[idx].ReadOnly = isReadOnly;
             dgv.Columns[idx].HeaderText = dgv.Columns[idx].Name + "_" + "Not_ReadOnly";
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    LockCols(0, dgv.Columns.Count / 2, true);
    LockCols(dgv.Columns.Count / 2 + 1, dgv.Columns.Count, false);
    sw.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

Comment: But i have a situation where i have lock a lot of cells, here i took columns as a sample. Imagine if there 55000 cells that i need to perform locking on based on some condition then how do i do it?

Comment: Whatever, that depends upon solely what you do inside the method. If you touch UI all over the method you should do it in main thread only. If you can post original code we can suggest better options.

Comment: So basically you're saying there is no way i can use multi-threaded code on the UI?

Comment: @LhtLohit Nope, Read my comment carefully. If any cpu bound operation or any IO bound operation you can do it in worker thread. If you touch UI all over the method doing it in UI thread is the way. Well, you can do it in worker thread but that will not perform better because you need plenty `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` calls. Without knowing what original code looks like It is hard to answer.

Comment: Can you show an example of a Worker thread? I can resolve this i will accept your answer.

Comment: @LhtLohit You have to understand that you did not provide me enough data to answer. With provided info I answered. Code without multi threading is far better (for scenario which you show). because you have never utilized the worker thread. Pleas post real code. What the real code is doing is important. For example: If you call database in real code, or you call some web service, or heavy computation then worker thread is going to help you. Code which you shown sets text in UI which cannot be done in worker thread. If you need more info please post real scenario with code.

Comment: i have posted new code - please see my edits. I want to lock all those cells which are empty. And i want to be able to this in a multi-threaded way - please know i dont really care about performance this is just an experiment that i am doing.